# WPF + Prism + Interaction not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have problem with setting up Interaction with Prism.

I would like to open "Edit" Window on button click. Window does open, but it does not have any content.

I have created my Popup view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.ClientEditView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:ClientEditViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="asd"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and backend:

```
public partial class ClientEditView : UserControl
{
    public ClientEditView(ClientEditViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = vm;
    }

    public ClientEditView()
    {
        this.ViewModel = new ClientEditViewModel();
    }

    public ClientEditViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ClientEditViewModel) DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ClientEditViewModel : BindableBase, IInteractionRequestAware
{
    private ClientEditNotification _notification;

    public ClientEditViewModel()
    {
    }


    public INotification Notification
    {
        get { return _notification; }
        set
        {
            if (value is ClientEditNotification)
            {
                this._notification = value as ClientEditNotification;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Notification);
            }
        }
    }

    public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; }
}
```

I have created Interaction in parent View + ViewModel:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.ClientDetailsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.ViewModels"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:OrtMan.Ribbon.ClientDetails.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:ClientDetailsViewModel}">


    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding EditItemRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction>
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:ClientEditView />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>


    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultImage" UriSource="/xxx;component/Images/noimage.jpg"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="1*" MaxWidth="400"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
            <Image Width="150" Height="150" Margin="0 10 0 10" Source="{StaticResource DefaultImage}"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPatient.Name}" Margin="10,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPatient.LastName}" Margin="10,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPatient.DateOfBirth, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" Margin="10,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ClientDetailsViewModel : BaseRibbonModule
{


    public ClientDetailsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IApplicationService applicationService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base(regionManager)
    {
        ButtonText = "Client Details";
        EditItemRequest = new InteractionRequest<ClientEditNotification>();
    }


    public InteractionRequest<ClientEditNotification> EditItemRequest { get; private set; }

    public override string MainView
    {
        get { return "ClientDetailsView"; }

    }

    public string MainText { get; set; }

    private DelegateCommand _editCommand;

    public DelegateCommand EditCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _editCommand ?? (_editCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    EditItemRequest.Raise(new ClientEditNotification() {Title = "a", Value = "xxx"});  
                },
                () =>
                {
                    return true;
                }));
        }
    }

}
```

- created single notification:

  public class ClientEditNotification : Confirmation
  {
      public String Value { get; set; }
  }

Result is, that after invoking EditCommand, new windows is opening, but nothing is inside it.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I forgot about something?

Thanks

--EDIT--

After some debugging I have found that:
- If I add something to Content property on Notification it shows as a string on Popup
- I have debugged with snoop my popup and I have found that proper view is in a content, but I have no idea why it's not showing anything

[image: Snoop Debug]

BTW. ClassNames may be different, because I have made 10 different project about this problems and no of them works.

Comment: You do not seem to have `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`in your XAML, which should locate, initialize/resolve and assign the ViewModel to the View's DataContext. Did you try adding it?

Comment: I have added it to both: ClientDetailsView and ClientEditView. No effect.

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: It isn't by chance just because you are missing the call to InitializeComponent() in your default constructor is it?  You have that call in your constructor that accepts the VM, but not the default ctor.  Which ctor is being called?